# Calculate percentage between two values in a JSON in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, for-loop

I have a JSON with daily data in it.

What I want to do is calculate, for each value, the percentage of difference between day n and day n+3.

`quote1` is day n, `quote2` is day n+3.

However, I can't use `quotes[i+3]` in the `for` loop, for obvious reasons.

Any idea? Thank you!

```
for (var i = quotes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  function percent(quote1, quote2) {
    var quote1 = parseInt(quote1);
    var quote2 = parseInt(quote2);
    return ((quote1 / quote2) -1 ) * 100;
  }
  console.log(percent(quotes[i].Close, quotes[i].Close) + ' %');
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it isn't really a good idea to place the `function` in the `for` loop:

```
function percent(quote1, quote2) {
  var quote1 = parseInt(quote1);
  var quote2 = parseInt(quote2);
  return ((quote1 / quote2) -1 ) * 100;
}
for (var i = quotes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  
  console.log(percent(quotes[i].Close, quotes[i].Close) + ' %');
};
```

This is just good practice, because you are defining your `function` every single time you got through the loop, its inefficient and pretty much defeats the purpose of creating a `function` which is to limit redundant code.

Next for your question, if you have a range of 3 over which you are always getting the difference, you can just offset your loop to end on `i=END-3=0`

```
for (var i = quotes.length - 1; i >= 3; i--) {  
  console.log(percent(quotes[i].Close, quotes[i-3].Close) + ' %');
};
```

or start on `i = Start + 3 = Length of List`

```
for (var i = (quotes.length - 1) - 3; i >= 0; i--) {  
  console.log(percent(quotes[i].Close, quotes[i+3].Close) + ' %');
};
```

**EDIT**

from the images of output you showed me I would recommend switching from using `parseInt` to `parseFloat` to preserve the decimal values.  This is what is causing the *strange* results.  For example:

```
percent(29.19,28.17) => 3.57... %
percent(29.65,29.24) => 0 %
```

This is occuring because you are calculating the percent change on the integer value of the input, and not including the decimal portion which is where the significant digits are:

Stepping through your `function percent`:

```
>>> percent("29.19","28.17");
    // Internal
    var quote1 = parseInt("29.19"); // quote1 now equals 29
    var quote2 = parseInt("28.17"); // quote2 now equals 28
    return ((quote1/quote2) - 1) * 100; 
    // ( (29/28) - 1 ) * 100
    // ( (1.0357142857142858) - 1) * 100
    // (0.0357...) * 100 = 3.57....
```

and for the second example:

```
>>> percent("29.65","29.24");
    // Internal
    var quote1 = parseInt("29.65"); // quote1 now equals 29
    var quote2 = parseInt("29.24"); // quote2 now equals 29
    return ((quote1/quote2) - 1) * 100; 
    // ( (29/29) - 1 ) * 100
    // ( (1) - 1) * 100
    // (0) * 100 = 0
```

Switch to `parseFloat` and everything should be ok.

```
function percent(quote1, quote2) {
  var quote1 = parseFloat(quote1);
  var quote2 = parseFloat(quote2);
  return ((quote1 / quote2) -1 ) * 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it was very helpful. I'm concerned with [the results](http://imgur.com/ePgG7a6), though. Are the 0% and the repetitions normal?

Comment: @user3041647 Could you rerun it with this: `console.log(quotes[i].Close + " " + quotes[i+3].Close + " " + percent(quotes[i].Close, quotes[i+3].Close) + ' %');` statement instead?  I would need to see the data that is being inputted to judge your results.

Comment: [Here you go!](http://imgur.com/hvbg514) Interesting, isn't it? (although I find it confusing)

Comment: @user3041647 you're output is off because you are rounding `float`s to `int`s and losing your decimal precision, see the edit to my post for more info.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Glad I learned about ``parse`` in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Why not start your for loop with quotes.length - 4?  You won't get meaningful answers for the top three quotes anyway.

```
for (var i = quotes.length - 4; i >= 0; i--) {
  function percent(quote1, quote2) {
    var quote1 = parseInt(quote1);
    var quote2 = parseInt(quote2);
    return ((quote1 / quote2) -1 ) * 100;
  }
  console.log(percent(quotes[i].Close, quotes[i+3].Close) + ' %');
};
```

Comment: Might want to move the function out of the loop

Comment: You will be redeclaring that function on each loop, where you only really need to define it once

Comment: because now you define the function again, and again, and again, for every quote. you only need the function once. i wouldn't even use a function here: console.log(((parseInt(quotes[i].Close) / parseInt(quotes[i+3])) - 1) * 100)